# How to hide hamburger icon on a certain fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Let's say I have 5 fragments (a,b,c,d,e) and I want to hide the hamburger icon on fragment a, but show the hamburger icon on fragment b,c,d,e. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
```